# How to get JSON data into a Razor view Script Block

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm just trying to get a  JSON string from my controller (MVC3 using Razor syntax) into the clients browser...

In My Controller I do this with a simple object (test) that contains an int and a list.

```
var jasonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(test);
ViewBag.JasonData = jasonData;
```

In the view I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @(ViewBag.JasonData);
</script>
```

Visual Studio shows the data looking fine but when it ends up in the Browser it has the escaping code around all the data which is not good.

```
&var initialData = {&quot;DateId&quot;:32,&quot;Scores&quo ....
```

This should be easy! What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `jason` or `json`? I hope it's the latter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()` to prevent the data from being encoded, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var initialData = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JasonData); 
</script>
```

Comment: VS 2012 is giving me a script error (showing as error, not warning) when using this.  Razor+Javascript parser bug?  The error is on the semicolon, ';'.

Comment: @yzorg FYI - if you write the line like `var initialData = @(Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonData));` the Intellisense Error goes away.

Comment: This works fine if i have the viewbag.JsonData in the Index method but how should i get the same if it is in some other action result other than Index???