# How to remove &quot; from my Json in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to inject json into my backbone.js app. My json has `&quot;` for every quote.

Is there a way for me to remove this?

I've provided a sample below:

```
[{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Name}]
```

Comment: Why not stop this from happening in the first place? At present you _don't_ have JSON at all, but something that looks a little bit like it.

Comment: It was encoding the quotes. It is a totally different issue not related to Json, but related to ASP.NET MVC. We may want to delete this post.

Comment: use this instead of replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147468/node-js-json-stringify-causing-quot-in-output-cant-parse-with-jquery

Comment: Since your comment mentions ASP.NET MVC, I'll throw in that the root cause of my issue was not using `@Html.Raw(jsonFromModel)` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493096/how-to-get-json-data-into-a-razor-view-script-block

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Presumably you have it in a variable and are using `JSON.parse(data);`. In which case, use:

```
JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```

You might want to fix your JSON-writing script though, because `&quot;` is not valid in a JSON object.

Comment: When I try this, I saw my js code change to that: `result.replace(/&#34;/g,'"')`

Comment: @kirlisakal were you able to get around this issue?

Comment: This works, but what if data has some value like this: `10&quot;6 inch display`?

Comment: Then you might want to fix your JSON-writing script.

Comment: I'm seeing this in an API that isn't mine. Why would it generate `&quot;` instead of `"`? (I think it's a react app)

Answer (score 22):

Accepted answer is right, however I had a trouble with that.
When I add in my code, checking on debugger, I saw that it changes from

```
result.replace(/&quot;/g,'"')
```

to

```
result.replace(/&#34;/g,'"')
```

Instead of this I use that:

```
result.replace(/(&quot\;)/g,"\"")
```

By this notation it works.

Comment: Yes, it works! but I need to customize Session object to fix this :(

Answer (score 5):

```
var data = $('<div>').html('[{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Name}]')[0].textContent;
```

that should parse all the encoded values you need.

Comment: That was the best solution. I had lots of escape charecters. This trick unescaped all

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to replace &quot with what you need to change it - chars, strings etc.

```
function solve(input) {
   const replaceWith = '"' // e.g. replace &quot; by "
   const result = input.replace(/&quot;/g, replaceWith)
   return result;
} 

console.log(solve('{&quot;x&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;y&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;z&quot;:&quot;10&quot;}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    let areaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
    areaElement.innerHTML = html;

    return areaElement.value;
}
```

Comment: It worked! The only change I would make is to remove the textarea at the end with areaElement.remove();

Answer (score 1):

In my case "quot" was replaced with other characters so I found a stupid but working workaround

```
str.replace(/&qu/g,'').replace(/ot\;/g,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

i used replace feature in Notepad++ and replaced `&quot;` (without quotes) with `"` and result was valid json

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using SQL then you can use:

update tablename
set payload = replace(payload, '&', chr(39))
where id = 'unique id';

Answer (score -2):

If you are using python then you can use:

```
import html
l = [{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Name}]
r = html.unescape(l)
```