# Node.js JSON.stringify() causing &quot; in output. Can't parse with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express, pug

I am using Node.js (with Express.js) to pass a JSON data object from the server to the client view.

When I render the JSON object directly to the view I get the JSON object shown on the page as expected (this WORKS):

```
pageprovider.findAllTag( function(error, pages){
    res.send(pages);
})
```

And my output looks like this (much bigger, many nested obj)

```
{"green":{"title":"green","pagesContaining": ""}}
```

When I try to pass it to my Jade View like this:

```
pageprovider.findAllTag( function(error, tagsJSONObj){
        //res.send(pages);

    pageprovider.findAll( function(error, pages){
        res.render('search_tags.jade', { locals: {
            title: 'Search by Tags',
            'pages': pages,
            tagsJSON: JSON.stringify(tagsJSONObj) //pass the tags data as a JSON obj
            }
        });
    }) //pageprovider.findAll
}) //pageprovider.findAllTag
```

---

**The problem**
When I pass 'tagsJSON' to the view, the output includes the html entities:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( "{&quot;name&quot;: 'value'}");
```

JQuery throws an error because it doesn't like '"'. How can I get Node to give me the proper quote, or get jQuery to accept this format?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking at the output in your browser `{"green":{"title":"green","pagesContaining": ""}}` ? If you are, then it's been HTML encoded for you. Probably because `pageprovider.findAllTag` does an HTML encode on what it passes back as the `tagsJSONObj` parameter. Show the code for `pageprovider.findAllTag`

Comment: What does `search_tags.jade` look like?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's because when you call

```
    res.render('search_tags.jade', { locals: {
        title: 'Search by Tags',
        'pages': pages,
        tagsJSON: JSON.stringify(tagsJSONObj) //pass the tags data as a JSON obj
        }
    });
```

`search_tags.jade` is meant to output HTML, so it encodes your quotes. You should use a renderer that doesn't HTML escape, or at least change your view so that your params aren't HTML encoded

If you don't want something in the output escaped, use `!{tagsJSON}` within the view. However, when outputting JSON, there's no need for a view. you can just take your object, call `JSON.stringify`. I don't use JADE so I'm not sure if there is a way to create view that can just call `JSON.stringify()`, but that's what I've done in JSP, velocity, ASP, PHP and Code Igniter (not using `JSON.stringify`, instead it uses a JSON tool for the given language)

Comment: Thank you. !{tagsJSON} worked beautifully. I want to recreate my data set on the client with JS so I can easily manipulate the DOM using that dataset. I didn't want to do an additional Ajax request to fetch that data. That's why I wanted to pass my JSON obj to the JS inside the view. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JamisCharles I see, your view is not displaying only JSON, then `!{tagsJSON}` is the right way.

Comment: This is the correct answer based on the question (which crucially omitted the view code), however, I think it would be better to only pass data/objects to the view, and do the stringify operation there. Try `!{JSON.stringify(data)}` in your jade template. That's what I settled on.

Answer (score 22):

in ejs, its `<%- tagsJSON %>`

```
          ^ <---- Note the "-"
```

Comment: Might be obvious but note the - instead of = after <%

Answer (score 11):

Better solution when using Swig.js

`{{ data|json|raw }}`

Comment: Good approach, if you're using Swig that is.

Comment: thank you, i wonder how to parse html tag in swig, now i know by using `safe`

Comment: that's awesome and fixes the issues that the ` | json_encode` does not cover!

Answer (score 5):

### Swig Templating Engine method:

Since Swig hasn't been mentioned, I'll add my version in.

I came across this problem today and spent a good few hours trying to get it to work so I could send data to Chart.js: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

In my case, I was using Geddy.js instead of Express.js. Like the original poster, I also got the html escaped JSON string problem.

I am using Swig templating engine.

Thanks to Juan Mendes for mentioning **html escaping**, I found this discussion by the developer of Swig:

https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith-swig/pull/1

Which led me to search for an option to disable auto escaping.

I first tried:

```
{{ data|raw }} // didn't work
```

as it was mentioned in the github page, but that didn't work so I went to documentation and found this:

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/

Gold! :D

So **final solution**:

```
{% autoescape false %}
var data = {{ data }}
{% endautoescape %}
```