# node.js render and send in same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can i render jade and send some code after render without replace jade code by new code i sent it

here is example

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
//res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
res.render('user', { title: 'Express' }); 




  //after render user jade i want to send some json to user
   res.contentType('application/json');
   res.send(json_code);

 });
```

When i run this code its replace the jade with json code !
how to solve it ?

Comment: you can either send JSON or HTML to client on one request. you cannot send both.

Comment: any idea to make both or send them togther ?

Comment: either you add the json data to the HTML page using a script tag (e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437295/jade-template-how-to-pass-concrete-object-to-pages), or the HTML page you send needs to initiate another request, to get the json data seperatly, either in a XHR, or in JSONP

Comment: Explain what your trying to accomplish, people can give you better advice this way.

Comment: @tmcgoo i want after render html  send some json file thats contain javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render the HTML page and inject the `json_code` to be used in a `script` tag:

JS:

```
router.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    var json_code = { 'hello': 'world' };
    res.render('user', { title: 'Express', data: JSON.stringify(json_code) }); 
});
```

HTML/JADE:

```
script
    var json_code = JSON.parse(#{data})
```

Comment: its show my script like this <script>&quot;{\&quot;type\&quot;:\&quot;pagelet\&quot;,\&quot;i </script>

Comment: I solve the problem of output from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147468/node-js-json-stringify-causing-quot-in-output-cant-parse-with-jquery