# &quot; is JSON string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, encoding, jstree

I have a JSON string which looks like this when displayed in an ASP.NET MVC page using @Model.JsonData

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "text": "Consumer",
    "parent": "#";
  }
]
```

When I use the same @Model.JsonData in the JavaScript code it is encoded as:

```
[
  {
    &quot;id&quot;: 123,
    &quot;text&quot;: &quot;Consumer&quot;,
    &quot;parent&quot;: &quot;#&quot;
  }
]
```

Why does the JavaScript segment encode the double quotes?

When the double quotes are encoded the jstree plugin expecting JSON data does not work.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': function ()
                {
                    var jsonTreeData = @Model.JsonTreeData;
                    return jsonTreeData;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Error message:
"SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant"

Comment: ``var json = JSON.parse('@Model.JsonData')``

Comment: The above comment does not work because the @Model.JsonTreeData encodes automatically and throws "SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove &quot; from my Json in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244824/how-to-remove-quot-from-my-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Replace `&quot;` with `"`

```js
var data = JSON.parse("[{&quot;id&quot;: 123,&quot;text&quot;: &quot;Consumer&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;: &quot;#&quot;}]".replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: The problem is that the encoded string in the javascript code snippet for jstree raises an error:"SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant"

Answer (score 0):

In your **controller** Pass **Model.JsonData** this way

```
Model.JsonData = new HtmlString("Your String or Json");
```

Add **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;** if HtmlString is not accessible.