# jQuery parse json error in valid json

Tags: jquery, json

I have json inside a data attribute. It's valid in online validators like http://jsonlint.com/. Still it trows an error. What is wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="seo" data-seo-controller='{"values":{"child_count":"0","type":"tables"},"title":{"field":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6 llasdas","template":"This page has {{child_count}} {{type}}!","prefix":"","suffix":" - Products","fallback":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6 llasdas","full":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6 llasdas - Products","full-replaced":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6 llasdas - Products"},"description":{"field":"rwerwe wer &quot; &#039; ewrerte fsd :&#039;","fallback":"rwerwe wer &quot; &#039; ewrerte fsd :&#039;","full":"rwerwe wer &quot; &#039; ewrerte fsd :&#039;","full-replaced":"rwerwe wer &quot; &#039; ewrerte fsd :&#039;","template":"","prefix":"","suffix":"","limit":155},"url":{"edit":"http:\/\/localhost\/seo\/panel\/pages\/saved-value\/url","preview":"seo\/saved-value"}}'>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var json = $('.seo').attr('data-seo-controller');
   controller = jQuery.parseJSON( json );
   console.log(controller);
});
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/q89hph0L/

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

**UPDATE:**

It seems to work if copy paste the json into a string and parse it. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q89hph0L/4/

So, it cannot have json as data attribute?

Comment: &quot; is causing the problem. try to handle it.

Comment: It might be interesting to know how you generate this data

Comment: @Brewal With PHP. Some of that data are going into forms and other data into html attributes. That's why some characters are escaped.

Comment: the single quote should not be encoded to "&quot;" in the first place. Try to use `html_entity_decode()` with php

Comment: Possibly this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269228/1702612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&quot;` gets rendered by browser into `"`, see: [How to escape double quotes in title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752769/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-title-attribute). It's the same usecase as yours.

Solution is to replace `&quot;` with `\"` and when using `jQuery.data` you don't even have to parse the string with `JSON.parse()`. Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0qryjrya/.