# PHP array to jQuery, using json_encode: &qout; instead of "

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig, silex

I am trying to send a php array to jquery

This is my array before json encode:

```
Array ( [0] => 30-Dec [1] => 31-Dec [2] => 1-Jan [3] => 2-Jan [4] => 3-Jan [5] => 4-Jan [6] => 5-Jan [7] => 6-Jan )
```

This is it after the json encode:

```
["30-Dec","31-Dec","1-Jan","2-Jan","3-Jan","4-Jan","5-Jan","6-Jan"]
```

If I make a variable in jquery with the json encoded array and print this in the console I got the following:

```
[&quot ;30-Dec&quot ;,&quot;31-Dec&quot ;,&quot ;1-Jan&quot ;,&quot ;2-Jan&quot ;,&quot ;3-Jan&quot ;,&quot ;4-Jan&quot ;,&quot ;5-Jan&quot ;,&quot ;6-Jan&quot ;]
```

But then without the spaces between the `t` and `;`

I am using twig and silex for my websites.

***EDIT*

This is my code PHP code**

function getDates($startTime, $endTime) {
            $day = 86400;

```
        $format = 'j-M';

        $startTime = strtotime($startTime);

        $endTime = strtotime($endTime);

        $numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;

        $days = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numDays; $i++) {

            $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));

        }

        return $days;

    }

    $days = getDates($lastday, $today);

    $days = json_encode($days);
```

**This is my twig/jquery code**

var days = '{{ days }}';

console.log(days);

Comment: I don't think this is the result of json_encode. json_encode should be returning [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), shouldn't it?

Comment: So.... What is your code?

Comment: problem isn't with `json_encode` , far more likely a result of running it through templating engines. Read the manual docs for `json_encode`

Comment: Show the code where you encode the array, where you pass it to the view, and how you echo it in the view.

Comment: Why don't you use Silex's helper to return a JSON Response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove &quot; from my Json in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244824/how-to-remove-quot-from-my-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Deciding how to present a given set of data to the user is the role of the view layer. Remove the json_encode call from your php code, it should return a simple array. Pass that to twig and do the encoding there:

```
{{ days|json_encode }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted before by charlietfl the templating Engine/Twig is escaping your data. An easy fix should be applying the `|raw` filter [0].

[0] http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html