# How to Parse JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am getting following JSON through AJAX call which is Invalid due to \t after bullet point, Due to this i am getting javaScript error in JSON.Parse(data.d) function.
Could you please suggest how to handle this situation ?

```js
{ "Initial" :[ 
                       {"IncidentNumber" : "INCB68686857575" ,
                       "IncidentStart": "22-Apr-2016 11:03" ,
                       "Title": "aaa", 
                       "ServiceName": "a",
                       "Status": "Service Down",
                       "UsersImpacted": "MULTIPLE" ,
                       "Circle": "a" ,
                       "RecoveryActivity": "•\tJohn Michel USA Country nextline•\tABC DEF GDH LMN India" ,
                       "EstimatedRestorationTime": "a" ,
                       "OwningOrLeadTeam": "a" ,
                       "SupportingTeams": "a" ,
                       "IncidentLead": "a",
                       "Resiliency": "To Be Determined",
                       "NextUpdateGMTTime": "17-May-2016 12:48" }]
}
```

Comment: this runs fine in my console panel. What do you observe as error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: @RegisPortalez
I am getting Invalid Character found and if i remove spacing between bullet point and ABC in 'Recovery Activity' then it works fine..But from back end instead of Spaced it is coming as '\t'.

Comment: Could you provide us with a snippet of the code you are using to parse the JSON ? if you would like to keep \t in the result you should probably escape the special character in the backend code

Comment: First thing is that this is already a valid json, there's no need to parse it. If it is in string form, then you can simply use `JSON.parse` to parse it ( not `JSON.Parse` ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove &quot; from my Json in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244824/how-to-remove-quot-from-my-json-in-javascript)

Comment: @LayonezWronskey ,  Vladimir Drenovski , Regis Portalez
i have updated my JSON, in above JSON I am getting problem with '\t'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
JSON.parse(stringified.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```

Comment: I am getting error as 'JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace' '

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to call `replace` on your `json string` object