# String to array, format

Tags: javascript

I passing some params from by back to my front through environment params. No problems with strings but I'm getting crazy to do it with an array.

1. Initial array format = `["one", "two", "three"]`
2. when I pass it to the front, it return `"[&quot;one&quot;, &quot;two&quot;, &quot;three&quot;]"`
3. So to solve thats, a little js tricks (`.replace(/&quot;/g, "'")`) give me that format : `"['one', 'two', 'three']"`

And now, I would like to transform it to a basic array javascript like this : `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Any ideas to solve that (with less code would be great obviously !)

Comment: You cant use arrays for that: environment variables are strings. allways! What you can do is to "serialize" the array on the backend with `<ENV_VAR> = JSON.serialize(...)` and "parse" it with `JSON.parse(<ENV_VAR>)` on the frontend.

Comment: You can refer to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244824/how-to-remove-quot-from-my-json-in-javascript Seems like the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace "`&quot;`" and then split by "`,`".

```js
let str = "[&quot;one&quot;, &quot;two&quot;, &quot;three&quot;]"
let ret = str.slice(1, -1).replace(/&quot;/g, "").split(",").map(x => x.trim());
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, unescape the HTML code by passing it through a temporary text area.
Second, use `JSON.parse()` to convert the unescaped String to a JavaScript array.

```js
escaped = "[&quot;one&quot;, &quot;two&quot;, &quot;three&quot;]"

const tmp = document.createElement("textarea");
tmp.innerHTML = escaped;
unescaped = tmp.value;
array = JSON.parse(unescaped);
document.write(array); // "one,two,three"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript `eval()` function to extract that string into array as follows.

```js
const input = "['one', 'two', 'three']";

console.log(eval(input));
```

Comment: You should avoid using eval, especially if you can simply enter `ENV_VAR = "<script> alert () </script>"` from outside

Answer (score 0):

send data as string from server to client as string

```
var x = ["one", "two", "three"];
let dataForExchange = x.tostring();
```

Now when data received at the client parse it into an array again

```
var xArray = dataForExchange.split(',');
```